# Am I factoring $x^8 - 1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ correctly?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

I have the following:

$$x^8 - 1 = (x^4 - 1)^2 = (x^2 - 1)^4 = (x - 1)^8$$

From my understanding, because I am specifically factoring $x^8 - 1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, that means the terms $x^q + 1$ and $x^q - 1$ are equivalent. So $x^8 - 1 = (x^4 + 1)(x^4 - 1) = (x^4 - 1)^2$.

Comment: I think it's correct. You can also write it as $x-1$ since $x^8\equiv x(\text{mod 2})$.

Comment: @Wolfuryo I'm confused as to why $x^8 \equiv x \,\, (mod \,\, 2)$. Would you mind explaining this simplification?

Comment: @Wolfuryo $x-1$ is not correct. $x^8-1$ and $x-1$ are different polynomials also in $\mathbb Z_2$. The value modulo $2$ is in fact the same as the value of $x-1$ for every $x$ , but this is not the point of polynomial factorizations modulo $2$.

Comment: The factorization in irreducible factors is $(x-1)^8$ , the other factorizations are also correct.